# io.mockk.MockKException: no answer found for: SavedStateHandle(#1).set(Key, Something)

Tags: kotlin, mockk, viewmodel-savedstate

I have a ViewModel class as below (simplified to demonstrate the problem I faced)

```
class MyViewModel(private val savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle) : ViewModel() {
    init {
        savedStateHandle.set(KEY, "Something")
    }
}
```

I have a MockK testing class as below

```
@Test
fun `test something simple`() {
    val savedStateHandle = mockk<SavedStateHandle>()
    val viewModel = MyViewModel(savedStateHandle)
    verify { savedStateHandle.set(MyViewModel.KEY, "Something") }
}
```

By running the test I get the below error

```
io.mockk.MockKException: no answer found for: SavedStateHandle(#1).set(Key, Something)
```

I guess I need to handle the `set` for `SavedStateHandle` as well. How could I do so in `MockK`?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Looks like I need to `relaxed = true` to my Mock, to make it just return a default value.

```
@Test
fun `test something simple`() {
    val savedStateHandle = mockk<SavedStateHandle>(relaxed = true)
    val viewModel = MyViewModel(savedStateHandle)
    verify { savedStateHandle.set(MyViewModel.KEY, "Something") }
}
```

The other option is to mock the return value...

```
@Test
fun `test something simple`() {
    val savedStateHandle = mockk<SavedStateHandle>()
    every {savedStateHandle.set(MyViewModel.KEY, "Something") } returns Unit
    val viewModel = MyViewModel(savedStateHandle)
    verify { savedStateHandle.set(MyViewModel.KEY, "Something") }
}
```

Comment: With first solution I got: `java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.Object cannot be cast to class Something (java.lang.Object is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; Something is in unnamed module of loader 'app')` ;;;;; and with the second solution I got: `io.mockk.MockKException: no answer found for: SavedStateHandle(#1).get(Something)`